# RTMFP / peer-to-peer over public Internet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, p2p, rtmfp

Looking at this example - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/p2p_apps_cirrus_lccs.html based on the same functions, I've created a little video conferencing app, which works great on computers in the same building. However when I start testing it remotely I can't get the 'InStream' to display. I'm passing the correct farID to the Netstream class..Is there something I'm missing? I'm not getting any errors

Comment: Try your project with a flash player debug version to see if you have errors. You can download flash player from [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm running with a debugger player, no errors.

Comment: I don't know exactly the cirrus project, but I think that your two machines should be connected to the same multicast network, no ?!

Comment: What netstream and netconnection event logs do you have (on both side)? It should tell you what's happening. And which server do you use? AMS on a local machine? Cirrus with sample key? MonaServer?

Comment: You likely have a firewall in place that is blocking UDP traffic to outside sources.  Without poking a hole for your application through that firewall, it will not work.   Unfortunately, using peer-to-peer RTMFP requires a huge range of ports to be opened (which IT departments don't like)

Comment: Thanks @Batman, you're right. It does seem to work on certain connections and in more corporate setups it fails. Although the initial connections are being established, it seems  the UDP traffic is being blocked. On computers the App fails on, the http://cc.rtmfp.net/  test "Source UDP port number is preserved from original connection" also equals No. So I'm guessing that is related. However on those same computers I have got it working over RTMP instead. Just working on how to gracefully fall back from RMTFP to RTMP now :)

Comment: Rtmp uses only one TCP port (1935 I believe) and most firewalls have it opened by default.    Just try to connect over rtmfp, and if that fails, connect by rtmp.   It will take quite a while to timeout though, so you may want to make a `Timer` that after 5 seconds of no response, just move on to RTMP.

Comment: I tried that, but it's not bullet proof. As it could connect via rtmfp but it would fail when testing  "Source UDP port number is preserved from original connection" even when the NetStreams were successful. This link was useful - https://forums.adobe.com/thread/698233